# Knockoutjs afterRender is not firing on native template

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Consider some HTML markup which uses MVC partial view to create a dialog.
When selectedMember is set on the viewmodel, the dialog will be populated and the openDialog event gets called which calls Jquery dialog("open").

I use the afterRender event to ensure unobtrusive validation works since the dialog is dynamically created.  However the afterRender function is never called?

```
<div id="dlgAddMember" class="hidden" data-bind="with: selectedMember, openDialog: selectedMember, afterRender:hookupValidation">
        @Html.Action(ekmMvc.People.AddMemberDialog())
</div>
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working. It seems this was working ok using Jquery template engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify it like:

```
data-bind="template: { data: selectedMember, if: selectedMember, afterRender: hookupValidation }"
```

When you do not specify a name for the template, then it will use anonymous templates.  So, this is the equivalent of `with` with an afterRender.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, I still can't get "openDialog: selectedMember" to bind when the selectedMember is set to not null. It is a custom binding which calls $(element).dialog("open"). I need to be able to 1) populate the dialog in the div, 2) open it, 3) hookup the validation.  Struggling with this...

Comment: Can you put something in jsFiddle?

Comment: Do you know if there is a link anywhere to an existing fiddle? I always find it difficult building one up from scratch...

Comment: Thanks, I got this working in the end. Your jsfiddle gave me a clue actually. The openDialog custom binding was in the template object itself, before the afterRender event.  Moving the openDialog binding outside of the template definition resolved the problem.